# Dell laptop hangs on bootup

Tags: laptop, boot, memory, dell-studio

I've got a Dell 1535 Studio laptop. It's hanging on boot up. It's just at the dell load up screen at the VERY start of boot up. Sometimes it doesn't even display the bootup screen and when it does it normally spouts out something like the following error:

```
`Memory write/read failure at 00560644 read 563956b9 expecting 56b956b9

To resolve this issue try to reseat the memory`
```

I've tried reseating the memory, anyone have any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It definitely sounds like a memory issue.

Does your laptop have multiple memory chips installed? If so, try leaving only 1 chip installed to see if you can identify the bad memory chip.

If you only have 1 chip installed, see if you can borrow a compatible memory chip from a friend or your local computer repair shop (may need to do that one in store) to see if replacing the memory resolves the issue.